# How to migrate Angular rc2 from rc1?

Tags: angular, migration

I am developing my own component with **control value accessor** and some of lifecycle of angular 2 rc.2. I need whole changes from rc1 to rc2. Please help me.
What are the things I have to change?

Comment: This question, in it's current state, is too broad

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of changes that came to RC.2  that you might want to consider:

source: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc2-2016-06-15

```
2.0.0-rc.2 (2016-06-15)

Bug Fixes

Animation: Problem with decimals using commas as decimal separation (5f3d02b), closes #6335 #6338
animations: Ensure AUTO styles are cleared at the end of the state-change animation (55860e1), closes #9014 #9015
animations: Ensure the web-animations driver converts style props to camel-case (4d51158), closes #9111 #9112
bootstrap: Swap coreBootstrap() and coreLoadAndBootstrap() arguments (f95a604)
browser: Platform code cleanup (75e6dfb)
build: Change publish-build-artifacts.sh to work with new packaging system (d414734)
build: Declare the secure GITHUB_TOKEN_ANGULAR for package publishing from Travis (ff40072)
build: Fix an error in package publishing step where the script errors when a UMD bundl (bac1a6e)
build: Fix broken e2e test Travis task by running the right variation of sed on Travis (267d864)
build: Force a compatible baseURL for systemjs-builder (e0c83f6), closes #7167 #7360
build: Hook up publish-build-artifacts to Travis (97a1084)
build: Release compiler_cli packages along with rest of @angular packages and use ANGUL (9a05ca9)
build: update API spec to include the return value. (b60eecf)
ci: extra API in public_api_spec (f154e2c)
ci: incorrect import (cb980d3)
ci: make ci fail when compiler integration test fails (5941c92)
codegen: codegen all files in the program, not just roots (0d71345), closes #8475
compiler: Support for comment finishing with multiple dashes (60a2ba8), closes #7119
compiler: Added support for '* as m' style imports. (#9077) (e178ee4)
compiler: Added unit test to ReflectorHost and fixed issues (#9052) (0658eb4), closes [(#9052](https://github.com/(/issues/9052)
compiler: allow --noImplicitAny (817ddfa)
compiler: allow decorators defined in the same file (c1154b3)
compiler: emit correct types for literal arrays and maps. (a81923b)
compiler: have CSS parser support nested parentheses inside functions (ceac045), closes #7580
compiler: Improved error reporting of the static reflector. (cf3548a), closes #8978 #9011
compiler: properly report missing DI tokens (#9065) (3aca5ff), closes #8245
compiler: Reflector generates imports for '..' relative modules. (35ea02f), closes #9003 #9004
compiler: report errors for queries without selectors (#9018) (057abef), closes #4489
compiler: support lifecycle hooks in compiler_cli (7150ace)
compiler: support string tokens with . inside. (67c80fb), closes #8178
compiler: throw an error if variable with the same name is already defined. (#7209) (9036f78)
compiler_cli: allow to use builtin directives like NgIf, … (edec158), closes #8454
compiler_cli: normalize used directives (ff36b03), closes #8677
Control: Support select multiple with Control class (#8069) (84f859d)
core: accurate dev mode message for dart (#8403) (19e6538)
core: don’t detach nested view containers when destroying a view (e2b1e15), closes #8458 #8471
core: fix build (3ff20cd)
core: fix type of DebugNode.properties (#8964) (ddd2ac4), closes [(#8964](https://github.com/(/issues/8964)
core: Keep core exports separate from core/testing exports. (f4f6b87)
core: Keep core exports separate from core/testing exports. (#8930) (21fc1bb)
core: remove @internal annotation from PLATFORM_CORE_PROVIDERS (2ab1085), closes #8819
core: QueryList documentation (#8976) (b160ada)
di: type error in InvalidProviderError (c43636f), closes #7729
doc: Add missing comma in example (#8769) (00475f2)
docs: Fix a missing opening bracket (#8331) (d75f928), closes [(#8331](https://github.com/(/issues/8331)
DomRegistry: fix svg support (307d105)
facade: change EventEmitter to be sync by default (#8761) (e5904f4)
forms: radio buttons with different names should not share state (6dc88f5), closes #7051
forms: rename old forms folder to forms-deprecated (515a8e0)
forms: update accessor value when native select value changes (7a2ce7f), closes #8710
forms: update value and validity when controls are added (50acb96), closes #8826
forms: separate ngModelGroup from formGroupName (5c0cfde)
HTMLParser: properly report errors for not properly closed tags (#8999) (6f281ab), closes [(#8999](https://github.com/(/issues/8999) #7849
http: remove peerDep on @angular/common (29c2dcf)
http: respect custom Content-Type header in XHRConnection (#9131) (537e99b), closes #9130
http: Set response.ok (9234035), closes #6390 #6503
Location: make Location#platformStrategy:LocationStrategy property private (e93b3d2)
metadata: Allow spacing in multiple selectors (#7418) (b2e804c)
ngc: depend on correct tsc-wrapped package (16ef21d)
ngSwitch: use switchCase instead of switchWhen (#9076) (e1fcab7)
ngUpgrade: prevent digest already in progress (#9054) (7cefec7)
pipes: handle undefined value in slice (83c19a1), closes #7152
platform-browser: fix rollup config (f4b9728)
platform-browser: split dynamic bits in platform-browser into platform-browser-dynamic (6fc267f)
platform-server: should declare it's dependency on parse5 via package.json (9485f5a)
platform-server: correctly import private DOMTestComponentRenderer (7afee97)
playground: fix WebWorker single_thread example (29c77df)
query: set fixed @ViewChild / @ContentChild right after the view is created (c3d2459), closes #9040
renderer: remove unecessary setElementStyles method (e504d4e), closes #9000 #9009
Renderer: update signatures to make RenderDebugInfo optional (b7b5678), closes #8466 #8859
Request: Change Request.text's return type to string (b2e0946), closes #8138
router: Added pushState fallback for IE 9 browser. (bab6023), closes #6506 #7929
router: browser back and forward buttons not working correctly. (595bcdd), closes #8524 #8532
router: don't mark the RouterOutletMap as internal (45de65b)
router: ensuring MatchedUrl pass query params (7d853dd)
router: openning links in new tab (fa2ce81), closes #5908 #6806 #7749 #8806 #8821
router: provide a top-level route segment for injection (b8136cc)
router: replace state when path is equal to current path (#8766) (b2a7fd0)
Router: do not kill event-emitter on navigation failure (cbeeff2), closes #7692 #7532 #7692
Router: replace state when normalized path is equal to current normalized path (2bf21e1), closes #7829 #7897
scripts: fix: correct failing to push into builds repo on rerun (17f317d)
security: support XSSI prefixes with and without commas. (729dc3b)
test-runner: make karma internal reporter compatible with 0.13.20 (#8977) (fe8a7b0)
testing: add discardPeriodicTasks to be used with fakeAsync (#8629) (0cb93a4), closes #8616
tests: Execute the security specs only once (9634e8d)
travis: pin the version of tsickle for offline_compiler_test (7aa1790)
tsickle: put the tsickle support code at EOF (3cfe281)
typings: remove rxjs workaround (798bfac), closes #7198
upgrade: allow deeper nesting of ng2 components/directives (#8949) (48bf349)
upgrade: allow functions for template and templateUrl (#9022) (a19c4e8)
upgrade: Ensure upgrade adapter works on angular.js 1.2 (#8647) (cbc8d0a)
upgrade: fallback to root ng2 injector when element is compiled outside the document (#86 (db82906)
upgrade: make bindings available on $scope in controller & link function (#8645) (6cdc53c)
Features

animations: provide support for offline compilation (fa0718b)
animations: support styling of the default animation state (36d25f2), closes #9013
build: Added a version stamp in .metadata.json files. (2d8f776), closes #8974 #8981
ChangeDetectorRef: make detectChanges() correct (6028368), closes #8599
common: DatePipe supports ISO string (abc266f), closes #7794
common/datePipe: change date formatter to use correct pattern closes #7008 (#8154) (324f014), closes #7008 [(#8154](https://github.com/(/issues/8154)
compiler: Add support for limited function calls in metadata (5504ca1)
compiler: Add support for <ng-container> (0dbff55)
ComponentResolver: Add a SystemJS resolver for compiled apps (#9145) (a6e5ddc)
core: add a component resolver that can load components lazily using system.js (1a0aea6)
core: introduce support for animations (5e0f8cf), closes #8734
core/linker: add SimpleChanges type to lifecycle_hooks to simplify OnChanges signature (0a872ff), closes #8557
debug: collect styles and classes for the DebugElement (155b882)
enableDebugTools: return ComponentRef (4086b49)
forms: add new forms folder (4c39eac)
forms: add the submitted flag to NgForm and NgFormModel directives (420e83a), closes #2960 #7449
forms: allow ngModel to register with parent form (4ed6cf7)
forms: compose validator fns automatically if arrays (61960c5)
forms: support setting control name in ngModelOptions (a191e96)
forms: add easy way to switch between forms modules (22916bb)
HtmlLexer: add support for alphabetic cases (43148d8)
http: added withCredentials support (95af14b), closes #7281 #7281
http: automatically set request Content-Type header based on body type (0f0a8ad), closes #7310
http: implement Response.prototype.toString() to make for a nicer error message (89f6108), closes #7511
http: set the statusText property from the XMLHttpRequest instance (3019140), closes #4162
i18n: extract messages (ac11567)
i18n: support implicit tags/attributes (3e5716e)
i18n: generate error on unknown cases (5267115), closes #9094
i18n: Add file paths to error messages (fe01e2e)
metadata: emit all methods (29700aa)
NgTemplateOutlet: add context to NgTemplateOutlet (164a091), closes #9042
NgZone: isStable (587c119), closes #8108
platform-browser-dynamic: re-add a deprecated platform-browser-dynamic (172a566)
platform-browser-dynamic: fix public exports for web-worker related symbols (6e62217)
regex_url_paths: add regex_group_names to handle consistency with serializers (ce013a3), closes #7554 #7694
renderer: add a setElementStyles method (1ac38bd)
router: export RouterLink and RouterOutlet (#8912) (1c92903)
router: update router to support lazy loading (0f1465b)
SchemaRegistry: add Node.textContent (3b80ab5), closes #8413
security: add an HTML sanitizer. (f86edae)
security: add tests for style sanitisation. (7b6c4d5)
security: add tests for URL sanitization. (7a524e3)
security: allow data: URLs for images and videos. (dd50124)
security: allow url(...) style values. (15ae710), closes #8514
security: Automatic XSRF handling. (4d793c4)
security: complete DOM security schema. (040b101)
security: document iframe src to be TRUSTED_URL. (3463047)
add minified bundles (9175a04)
security: expose the safe value types. (50c9bed), closes #8568
security: fill in missing security contexts. (67ed2e2)
security: strip XSSI prefix from XHR responses. (df1b1f6)
security: support transform CSS functions for sanitization. (8b1b427), closes #8514
security: warn users when sanitizing in dev mode. (3e68b7e), closes #8522
shadow_css: add encapsulation support for CSS @supports at-rule (cb84cbf), closes #7944
ViewEncapsulation: default ViewEncapsulation to configurable (f93512b), closes #7883
BREAKING CHANGES

Location#platformStrategy property was previously accidentally exported as public If any application requires access to the current location strategy, it should be accessed via DI instead by injecting the LocationStrategy token. The likelihood of anyone actually depending on this property is very low.

DirectiveNormalizer takes new constructor arguments, config:CompilerConfig.

Parser constructor required new parameter config: CompilerConfig as second argument.

Bundles are now in the bundles/ subdirectory within each package

HTML, style values, and URLs are now automatically sanitized. Values that do not match are escaped or ignored. When binding a URL or style property that would get ignored, bind to a value explicitly marked as safe instead by injection the DOM sanitization service:

class MyComponent {
  constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) {
    // ONLY DO THIS FOR VALUES YOU KNOW TO BE SAFE! NEVER ALLOW USER DATA IN THIS!
    this.safeStyleValue = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('rotate(90deg)');
    // then bind to `safeStyleValue` in your template.
  }
}
PLATFORM_PIPES and PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES now are fields on CompilerConfig. Instead of providing a binding to these tokens, provide a binding for CompilerConfig instead.

CompilerConfig used to take positional arguments and now takes named arguments.

Deprecation

Parse5DomAdapter will no longer be exported from @angular/platform-server as a public API as of RC.3. A new function called serverBootstrap() will be provided, which will automatically set the correct document during platform initialization.
Reverts

Revert fix(compiler): support string tokens with . inside. (cc86fee)
```